# Calculating returning active users SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, lag, retention

I am running a query that returns the count distinct of active users per different products grouped by day and country. I also added two columns 'previous_day_active_users' and 'returning_users' which return the number of users active in the previous day and the number of users active both in the previous and the current day. I want to do this in order to calculate the retention rate (returning_users / previous_day_active_users).
The problem is the numbers don't match. In addition, 'previous_day_active_users' and 'returning_users' always match, which doesn't make sense.
I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Query:

```
WITH active_users AS (
    SELECT
        date_trunc('day'::text, customer_kpis_hourly.time_eet) as time_eet,
        customer_kpis_hourly.market_code,
        customer_kpis_hourly.user_id,
        customer_kpis_hourly.active,
        LAG(customer_kpis_hourly.active) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time_eet) AS prev_active,
        customer_kpis_hourly.active_casino,
        customer_kpis_hourly.active_virtual_sports,
        customer_kpis_hourly.active_poker,
        customer_kpis_hourly.active_sportsbook
    FROM delivery.customer_kpis_hourly
    WHERE customer_kpis_hourly.time_eet >= '2021-01-01'
    AND customer_kpis_hourly.time_eet < '2021-01-05'
    AND customer_kpis_hourly.active
),
previous_day_active_users AS (
    -- Calculate previous day's active users
    SELECT
        user_id,
        time_eet - INTERVAL '1 day' AS previous_day
    FROM active_users
    WHERE prev_active
)
SELECT
    'D'::text AS time_gran,
    date_trunc('day'::text, active_users.time_eet) AS time_eet,
    active_users.market_code,
    count(DISTINCT active_users.user_id) FILTER (WHERE active_users.active) AS active_user,
    count(DISTINCT active_users.user_id) FILTER (WHERE active_users.active_casino) AS active_casino,
    count(DISTINCT active_users.user_id) FILTER (WHERE active_users.active_virtual_sports) AS active_vs,
    count(DISTINCT active_users.user_id) FILTER (WHERE active_users.active_poker) AS active_poker,
    count(DISTINCT active_users.user_id) FILTER (WHERE active_users.active_sportsbook) AS active_sb,
    count(DISTINCT previous_day_active_users.user_id) as previous_day_active_user,
    count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN previous_day_active_users.user_id IS NOT NULL THEN active_users.user_id END) AS returning_users
FROM
    active_users
LEFT JOIN
    previous_day_active_users
    ON active_users.user_id = previous_day_active_users.user_id
--     AND date_trunc('day'::text, active_users.time_eet) = previous_day_active_users.previous_day
GROUP BY
    'D'::text, date_trunc('day'::text, active_users.time_eet), active_users.market_code
```

Comment: Don't forget to add a tag for the dbms used.

Comment: Please don’t link to images, add all relevant information to your question as editable text

Comment: Please update your question to provide table definitions (ddl), sample data, and expected results from that data. All as formatted text -**no images**. Additional benefit would be provide a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). You need only include relevant columns. (perhaps just 1 of the FILTERed columns).

Answer (score 0):

When you compute `previous_day_active_users`, you basically compute `time_eet - INTERVAL '1 day' AS previous_day` for the `user_id` given where

```
LAG(customer_kpis_hourly.active) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY time_eet) AS prev_active
```

evaluates as true. But this does not seem to actually check whether the user was really working on the previous day. instead, you will need to apply something like this:

```
SELECT <your fields>
FROM delivery.customer_kpis_hourly curr
LEFT JOIN delivery.customer_kpis_hourly prev
ON curr.user_id = prev.user_id AND
   prev.time_eet >= '2021-01-03' AND
   prev.time_eet < '2021-01-04'
WHERE
   curr.time_eet >= '2021-01-04' AND
   curr.time_eet < '2021-01-05'
```

That would create you pairs  or `curr` and `prev` and you can easily convert this into an aggregate query that counts the total number of `curr.user_id` as the number of active users and the total of not null `prev.user_id` as the users active on the previous day. Then you can compute their difference or ratio.